# SX1276 Interrupt Flags never clear, and digital IO lines never rise/fall

Tags: arduino, interrupts, beaglebone-black, lora, sx1276

I am using an SX1276 chip from Paradisetronic. I adapted the Arduino RadioLib library to my board (Beaglebone Black Rev C). I noticed that the IRQ flags will not be cleared. According to the [manual](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/761/sx1276-1278113.pdf) (page 111) writing a 1 to these bits clears the interrupt, but this does not happen for me for some reason (see attached image captured by logic analyzer). The lower 7 bits remain set no matter what.

Furthermore, the chip allows for hardware interrupt signals to be sent, but no matter what happens no signals occur, even though I do set the modes appropriately ([manual](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/761/sx1276-1278113.pdf) page 46). I would assume that if an interrupt happens, the appropriate interrupt signal would be triggered, but nothing happens. Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

PS. I did not post my code because its a few 100 lines, but I have cross-referenced with the [RadioLib Implementation](https://github.com/jgromes/RadioLib/blob/master/src/modules/SX127x/SX127x.cpp) and it is all identical, with the main difference being that I only converted the LoRa code as I am not planning on using FSK/OOK.

The SPI signals all look fine and the setup I do is identical to that in RadioLib

[image]

EDIT: I tried writing 0's instead of 1's to clear the IRQs and now the IRQs remain 0. It seems like this contradicts the manual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be a faulty powerline the board was connected to; it was not connected properly, resulting in the board resetting itself into FSK/OOK mode and thus the register containing the IRQ flags took on a different meaning and value.